# Overwriting HTML Page with $_POST

Tags: php, post, overwrite

I expected clicking the "submit" button would overwrite the HTML page with the two echo statements. However, no overwrite occurs. The page is connected to Apache.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    // if page is not submitted to itself echo the form
} 
else {
    echo("Hello, " . $_POST['username']);
    echo("Your password is " . $_POST['password'] . "!");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Visual Debate Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Visual Debate</h1>
    <form method="post" action="?">
        <div>Username: </div><div><input type="text" name="username" size="20" maxlength="20"></div>
        <div>Password: </div><input type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="15"></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The HTML and form are unconditionally being output in the code you posted.  The message you print should show up above the HTML code when the form is submitted however.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you're seeking for this:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    // if page is not submitted to itself echo the form
} 
else {
    echo("Hello, " . $_POST['username']);
    echo("Your password is " . $_POST['password'] . "!");
    die(); // stops the script execution! note that you can use die("like this") to output the "like this" and stop the script execution there.
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Visual Debate Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Visual Debate</h1>
    <form method="post" action="?">
        <div>Username: </div><div><input type="text" name="username" size="20" maxlength="20"></div>
        <div>Password: </div><input type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="15"></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried running this exact code as well. No results. I'm thinking this is an IDE problem. Thank you all.

Comment: IDE should not represent a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML for the page is outside of the `if` `else` logic of your PHP, meaning it will always be displayed. I would personally do something like this:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])):
        // Form was submitted to itself -- overwrite the form 
        echo("Hello, " . $_POST['username']);
        echo("Your password is " . $_POST['password'] . "!");
    else: 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Visual Debate Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Visual Debate</h1>
    <form method="post" action="?">
        <div>Username: </div><div><input type="text" name="username" size="20" maxlength="20"></div>
        <div>Password: </div><input type="password" name="password" size="15" maxlength="15"></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I originally arranged my code as you have, but I had the same problem. I'm running your exact code, but still no results.

Comment: Yeah, if you run my code (or Zlatan's) in [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/), you'll see that both approaches do work. Something's up with your server/PHP configuration.